# Java Random number but not zero

Tags: java, random, numbers

```
int num = 10;
Random rand = new Random();
int ran = rand.nextInt(num);
if (ran==0){          
  ran= ran+1;
}
System.out.println("random : "+ran);
```

This is what i have coded so far, is there a better way to do this? I feel that this is hard coding when random is 0, I added 1.

Comment: Your logic looks wrong. If the number is `0` then you'll increase the random number by `1` but not print out the value. Also in your example `1` it twice as likely to come up as any other number

Comment: I made an edit to fix the printing logic problem as it is not really relevant to the question.

Answer (score 31):

The problem with that code is that 1 is twice as likely as other numbers (as your effective result is 1 when `nextInt()` returns 0 or 1).

The best solution is to just *always* add 1 and request random numbers from a smaller range:

```
int rnd = rand.nextInt(num - 1) + 1;
```

Comment: what does maxValue-1 do ? is that the num i specify here ?

Comment: maxValue is the largest random number you will get. because you add one later you have to request maxValue-1

Comment: If `maxValue` is really the highest number you will get, then the `- 1` is wrong, as `nextInt(10)` returns numbers in range of `0..9`. Thus I edit the answer.

Comment: @Vlasec: you are correct. The parameter to `nextInt` is an exclusive bound, so if you want numbers from 1 to 10 then `nextInt(10) + 1` is what you need to use.

Comment: Could we edit the answer to denote that nextInt is exclusive and maxValue will never get returned, therefore the  "- 1" might not be necessary?

Comment: @dieresys is correct . -1 is not needed. Eg. to get random nos. from all positive integers(0 excluded), the formula will be : 
int rnd = rand.nextInt(Integer.MAX_VALUE) + 1

Answer (score 4):

I guess you are trying to get a random number between 1 and 'num'.

a more generic way can be :

```
int Low = 1;
int High = 10;
int R = r.nextInt(High-Low) + Low;
```

This gives you a random number in between 1 (inclusive) and 10 (exclusive). ( or use High=11 for 10 inclusive)

Comment: this is getting alittle confusing. I just want random number in 10 but not 0 .

Comment: Let me know what part is confusing you , will try to explain better

Comment: let say I want random number from 1 to less than 10.
which number should I specify?

Comment: use Low=1 and High=10 in above code you will have what you desire

Comment: so this will get integer between 1-9 ?

Comment: @newbieprogrammer Yes, this will generate numbers between 1 and 9 including both endpoints.  If you want to generate values of 10, you need to be like Spinal Tap and bump `HIGH` up by one to 11 because Java's generator doesn't include the actual upper limit.

Comment: Inclusive, exclusive ... that could be useful in floating points, but here, one can explain it with more clarity. I did.

Answer (score 2):

```
Random random = new Random();
int ran = random.nextInt(9) + 1; //10 is maxRandom value for this code. 1-10
```

Comment: so meaning , random.nextInt(num-1) + 1?

Comment: @newbieprogrammer `random.nextInt(maxValue)+1` `maxValue` set a range from **0** to `maxValue`. So if `maxValue` equal 9, your maximum integer will be 10.

Comment: random.nextInt(9) + 1 will give you 1-9.

Answer (score 1):

you also could do the following:

```
int randomNumber = 0;
do {
  randomNumber = rand.nextInt(maxValue);
} while(randomNumber == 0);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
int num,max=10,min=1;
Random r=new Random();
num=r.nextInt(max-min)+1;
```

You'll need this import at the beginning of your file:

```
import java.util.Random;
```

Answer (score 1):

Just lower the bound (num variable) by 1 and add 1 to the ran variable

```
    int num = 10;
    Random rand = new Random();
    int ran = rand.nextInt(num - 1) + 1;
    // or decrease num first n-- and then int ran = rand.nextInt(num) + 1
```

now the bound(limit) is 8 (inclusive for example, the final number is always exclusive) and if it comes 0, it will increase to 1 and if it comes 8, it will increase to 9, which was originally supposed to be the bound.

Answer (score 0):

Don't expect this functionality from `Random` and do it yourself as you should. One can do pretty much anything with the result - multiply, add (e.g. `2*nextInt(n)+1` for random odd number), use logarithmic scale for musical note frequencies, use a map or enum to obtain random objects ...

Method `nextInt(n)` is here only to give you `n` different values (from `0` to `n-1`). Don't ask more of it, implement the rest by yourself. If I understand your question well, you require numbers `1..9`, so you should ask for `nextInt(9)+1` to get `0..8` and then add `1`.

I hope this explanation helps, I saw many answers, but I didn't like the explanation in any of them.

Answer (score -1):

Try:

```
int num = 10;
Random rand = new Random();
int ran = rand.nextInt(num) + 1;
```